# Why do I get EOF after reading one line thourgh a named pipe using ifstream?

Tags: c++, named-pipes

At the command line I used mkfifo to create a pipe and confirmed that the file existed. `ls -al` gives:

```
prw-r--r--    1 user  group      0 Mar 30 11:52 my_pipe
```

I then use this code to attempt to read text line by line from that pipe:

```
ifstream pipe("/path/to/my_pipe");
string message;
while(getline(pipe, message) && message != "EXIT")
{
    cout << boolalpha << pipe.good() << endl << pipe.eof() << endl << pipe.bad() << endl;
}

cout << boolalpha << pipe.good() << endl << pipe.eof() << endl << pipe.bad() << endl;
```

Back to the command line I do `echo "banana" > my_pipe` and then the program exists with the following output:

```
true
false
false
false
true
false
```

This would indicate that the stream was in a good state after reading `banana` but that in the second call to `getline` I hit `EOF` and exited.

Why did I hit `EOF` and what can I do to keep the stream reading and in a good state until I read my special `EXIT` message?

**EDIT:**

Conclusions:

1. Use `fstream` instead of `ifstream`.
2. There apparently is a bug in libc++ as of this writing when it comes to fstream and pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EOF occurs on a pipe when it's closed by all the processes that have it open for writing. In your example, the only process that opens it for writing is the `echo` command; when it exits, , it closes the pipe, which results in EOF in the reading process.

If you want the pipe to stay open between each client writing to it, the way to do it is to open the pipe in read-write mode. That way, the reading process will also be a writing process, and as long as it has the pipe open it will never be closed by all the writers.

```
fstream pipe("/path/to/my_pipe");
```

Alternatively, you can keep the pipe open on the sending side by executing multiple commands within a single redirected processes:

```
( echo banana ; echo EXIT ) > my_pipe
```

Comment: I tried with a plain `fstream` and it just never returns from `getline`. Btw, `ios::in|ios::out` is the default mode for `fstream` so that's kinda redundant.

Comment: It should return from `getline` as soon as someone writes a line to it. Until then it should just wait. It will never leave the loop, though.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to keep the pipe open between echo commands.

Comment: Yes, it "should" return from `getline` but it just doesn't. Does it for you? Is that a bug in my implementation? Also, I expect this program to be long-lived, not just doing one-shot listening to a few echoed string.

Comment: I just tested it. I started the program in one window, then went to another window and did `echo foo > my_pipe`. The first window printed `true false false`.

Comment: Then I did `echo EXIT > my_pipe` in the second window, it printed the same message and exited.

Comment: OK, well I can tell you that on MacOS (Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)) the `getline` does not return if `pipe` is an `fstream`. It does return if it's an `ifstream` but then then next read is `EOF`. So... It looks like a bug in libstdc++. I suppose you're on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on Linux, I had trouble compiling my test program on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Final confirmation. I tried the exact same code in a Linux VM and it behaved as you predicted. On MacOS, it behaves as I described.