# keep reading from a named pipe after the first write has finished

Tags: named-pipes, eof, terminate

I want to feed chunks of input into a continuously running program (in my case it's gnuplot but it can be any program).
The problem is that after the first chunk the program thinks it's finished and terminates.
I'm demonstrating this with bash commands:

In terminal 1: create a named pipe and let `cat` listen to it:

```
mkfifo pipe
cat <pipe
```

In terminal 2: feed chunks into the pipe:

```
echo foo >pipe
echo bar >pipe
```

As soon as the first `echo` is done `cat` terminates. How can I make it keep going and process more input?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is buried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356003/829755) (a `C++` case):

> the way to do it is to open the pipe in read-write mode. That way, the reading process will also be a writing process, and as long as it has the pipe open it will never be closed by all the writers

Named pipes are designed to close when all writers (in this case the one echo command) are done. To keep it open use it in read-write mode:

```
cat <>pipe
```

At the end the reader has to be killed manually or by feeding a special sequences that it understands as exit command (because `EOF` no longer does that job). For instance in the case of gnuplot and other shell like programs I can say `echo exit >pipe`.