# SQL Server - Restore database using VDI and Named pipes. Error 38 (EOF)

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows, go, named-pipes

I developed an application to backup/restore Microsoft SQL Server databases from Windows using VDI and named pipes to transfer data.

The application has been created using Go and C++.

The backup works just fine.

However when I try to execute a restore it never finishes and SQL Server aborts with a 38 error (EOF).

I created a named pipe server from C++ and I read data from the pipe to SQL Server using VDI virtual device from C++ too. The named pipe client is just a Go reader/writer that reads from a disk file and writes to the pipe. This just for testing purposes, I will integrate with other writers in the future.

If I read directly from backup file I can restore the database, it only crashes when a named pipe is involved.

Anyone faced a problem like this?

EDIT 1: Yes, I am sure the backup is working. I can restore the database using the generated backup file from application using SQL Server Management Studio

EDIT 2: It is not the same case described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356003/4641116. I am already using read/write mode both named pipe client and server

EDIT 3: Here you have some code:

**C++ Named Pipe Server**

Creates pipe server and waits for client to start read from. I wrote here only VDC_Read case.

```cpp
    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(fname,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            1,
                            1024 * 16,
                            1024 * 16,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Named pipe %s created successfully\n", fname);
    }

      if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Starting transfer....\n");
        while (SUCCEEDED (hr))
        {
            dwTransferredBytes = 0;
            printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...\n");
            hr = vd->GetCommand(INFINITE, &cmd); 
            if (!SUCCEEDED (hr))
            {
                printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Error executing GetCommand. x%X\n", hr);
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully\n");
            }
                    
            switch (cmd->commandCode)
            {              
                case VDC_Read:
                    printf("[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_Read\n");
                    printf("[ExecuteTransfer] %d bytes to read....\n",  cmd->size);
                    
                    fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe, cmd->buffer, cmd->size, &dwTransferredBytes, NULL);
                    gle = GetLastError();
                    
                    if (fSuccess)
                    {
                        completionCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;
                        printf("[ExecuteTransfer] %d bytes read....\n", dwTransferredBytes);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if (gle == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
                            printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Read Error: client disconnected.\n"); 
                        else
                            printf("[ExecuteTransfer] Read Error, GLE=%d.\n", gle); 
                    }

                    if (dwTransferredBytes == 0)
                    {
                        printf("[ExecuteTransfer] 0 bytes transferred. Handling EOF...\n");
                        completionCode = ERROR_HANDLE_EOF;
                    }                    
                    break;
```

**Go named pipe client**

Very silly. Just to test that restore using named pipes is working. Reads a local file and writes into created C++ named pipe. 20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL is a valid backup file created by the application (as I previosuly said, I restored the database from SQL Server Management Studio from it)

```golang
        vReadFromFileFinished := make(chan bool)
        go func() {
            var vFileToRead *os.File
            var err error

            time.Sleep(time.Second * 3) // Wait for C++ to create named pipe
            vFilenameToRead := "c:\\tmp\\20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL"
            if vFileToRead, err = os.OpenFile(vFilenameToRead, os.O_RDONLY, 0666); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("[restore] Error opening file", vFilenameToRead)
                os.Exit(-1)
            }
            defer vFileToRead.Close()
            vReader := bufio.NewReader(vFileToRead)
            fmt.Println("[restore] Opening Named Pipe", gvDataSource.MSSQL.GetNamedPipeString())
            vFileToWrite, _ := os.OpenFile(gvDataSource.MSSQL.GetNamedPipeString(), os.O_RDWR, 0666)
            // defer vFileToWrite.Close()
            vWriter := bufio.NewWriter(vFileToWrite)
            var vBytesRead int
            var vBytesWritten int
            var vTotalBytesRead int
            var vTotalBytesWritten int
            vBuffer := make([]byte, 4096)
            for {
                vBytesRead, _ = vReader.Read(vBuffer)
                if vBytesRead == 0 {
                    break
                }
                // fmt.Printf("[restore] %d bytes read from %s file\n", vBytesRead, vFilenameToRead)
                vBytesWritten, _ = vWriter.Write(vBuffer)
                // fmt.Printf("[restore] %d bytes transferred to %s Named Pipe\n", vBytesRead, gvDataSource.MSSQL.GetNamedPipeString())
                vTotalBytesRead = vTotalBytesRead + vBytesRead
                vTotalBytesWritten = vTotalBytesWritten + vBytesWritten
            }
            fmt.Printf("[restore] Read from %s and write to % s finished\n", vFilenameToRead, gvDataSource.MSSQL.GetNamedPipeString())
            fmt.Printf("[restore] Total bytes read = %d\n", vTotalBytesRead)
            fmt.Printf("[restore] Total bytes written = %d\n", vTotalBytesWritten)
            vReadFromFileFinished <- true
        }()

        <-vReadFromFileFinished
```

**Application output sample**

You can see SQL Server VDI sequence: GetCommand - Execute code for the command - CompleteCommand. Everything works fine until it starts to read less bytes than required from SQL Server GetCommand. Then VDC_ClearError is executed and eventually GetCommand aborts (return code x80770004)

```
...

[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully
[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_Read
[ExecuteTransfer] 512 bytes to read....
[ExecuteTransfer] 512 bytes read....
[ExecuteTransfer] Completed command succesfully. Code: 1, completionCode: 0, bytes: 512
[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully
[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_Read
[ExecuteTransfer] 65536 bytes to read....
[ExecuteTransfer] 19968 bytes read....
[ExecuteTransfer] Completed command succesfully. Code: 1, completionCode: 0, bytes: 19968
[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully
[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_Read
[ExecuteTransfer] 65536 bytes to read....
[ExecuteTransfer] 20480 bytes read....
[ExecuteTransfer] Completed command succesfully. Code: 1, completionCode: 0, bytes: 20480
[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully
[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_ClearError
[ExecuteTransfer] vd address= x6058AE28
[ExecuteTransfer] cmd address = x67C10220
[ExecuteTransfer] Completed command succesfully. Code: 3, completionCode: 0, bytes: 0
[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] GetCommand executed successfully
[ExecuteTransfer] VDC_ClearError
[ExecuteTransfer] vd address= x6058AE28
[ExecuteTransfer] cmd address = x67C10260
[ExecuteTransfer] Completed command succesfully. Code: 3, completionCode: 0, bytes: 0
[ExecuteTransfer] Executing GetCommand...
[ExecuteTransfer] Error executing GetCommand. x80770004
[ExecuteTransfer] Unexpected termination: x80770004
[ExecuteTransfer] Disconnecting pipe
[restore] Read from c:\tmp\20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL and write to \\.\pipe\20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL finished
[restore] Total bytes read = 3105280
[restore] Total bytes written = 73728
[restore] Process finished!

...
```

**SQL Server Windows Event viewer error message**

Sorry, it is in spanish. :-)

Translation:

*BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read error in backup device '{80765A7E-8389-4A79-8E7C-5B87B25A41B7}'. Error 38(end of file reached.) from operative system.*

```
BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: error read en el dispositivo de copia de seguridad '{80765A7E-8389-4A79-8E7C-5B87B25A41B7}'. Error 38(Se ha alcanzado el final del archivo.) del sistema operativo.
```

EDIT 4: If I implement something to fill buffer completely after GetCommand and before calling CompleteCommand it didn't work but no EOF error in that case.

**Output**

```
[executeTransfer] Executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_GetCommand
[executeTransfer] C.VDC_Read
[executeTransfer] Starting read. Bytes to read: 65536
[executeTransfer] 65536 bytes transferred
[executeTransfer] Executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_CompleteCommand
[executeTransfer] Completion Ok
[executeTransfer] Executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_GetCommand
[executeTransfer] C.VDC_Read
[executeTransfer] Starting read. Bytes to read: 65536
[executeTransfer] 65536 bytes transferred
[executeTransfer] Executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_CompleteCommand
[executeTransfer] Completion Ok
[executeTransfer] Executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_GetCommand
[executeTransfer] Error executing C.ClientVirtualDevice_GetCommand. Exiting...
[executeTransfer] pVDCLient address =  0xc0007368c8
[executeTransfer] vCommand address =  <nil>
[executeTransfer] Unexpected termination: x-7F88FFFC
[executeTransfer] Total bytes transferred = 205312
[restore] Read from c:\tmp\20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL and write to \\.\pipe\20220531081651.CSYN4HMG0F3.emorydev.FULL finished
[restore] Total bytes read = 3105280
[restore] Total bytes written = 208896
[restore] Process finished!
```

You can see buffers completly filled, CompleteCommand working but GetCommand aborting after some VDC_Read executions.

If I take a look to event viewer, there is an abort message from SQL Server VDI:

```
SQLVDI: Loc=TriggerAbort. Desc=invoked. ErrorCode=(0). Process=5992. Thread=23732. Server. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\{3578E5E5-DB7F-404C-B49D-9BEB07D2C7BB}_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.
```

And in that case there is a dump like this:

```
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      * *******************************************************************************
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *   06/17/22 09:12:08 spid 23732
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *   Exception Address = 00007FFB2EA1188C Module(VCRUNTIME140+000000000000188C)
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *   Access Violation occurred reading address 000000D9E797AA20
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      * Input Buffer 224 bytes -
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *             RESTORE DATABASE emorydev FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE='{3578E5E5-DB7F
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *  -404C-B49D-9BEB07D2C7BB}' WITH REPLACE  
2022-06-17 09:12:08.77 spid52      *
```

I don't understand why there is an access violation at this point.

Comment: You need to loop `ReadFile` until you get enough data to fulfill the `GetCommand` request

Comment: Yeah, already tried and I get an abort from sqlserver. I am going to edit the question to show some output and error messages.